# Can I change the highlight of specific conceals?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

I'm using `:syn-cchar` to replace certain syntactic elements with Unicode characters (à la [vim-haskellConcealPlus](https://github.com/enomsg/vim-haskellConcealPlus)). Since I'm replacing several different elements, I'd like to be able to highlight some of them differently, to match whatever color they are without my plugin. However, all conceals appear to be hardcoded to use the `Conceal` syntax group. Is this possible to change?